# Referencing TextField in new Unity 4.6 Text Object

Tags: text, unity-game-engine

I have the following simple countdown script component attached the a Canvas object containing a single Text component. 'instruction' SHOULD reference the TextField, no? When I run it by calling startCountdown, the script hangs in the while loop at the line

```
Debug.Log ("TIMER countdown  time = "+time+ " and instruction = "+instruction);
```

The instruction variable doesn't trace out at all. The public var 'time' is set to some value greater than 0 in the inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

    public int time;

    Text instruction;

    public void Start () {
        instruction = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    public void startCountdown() {
        StartCoroutine (countdown ());
        Debug.Log ("YES TIMER START!");
    }

    IEnumerator countdown() {
        while (time > 0) {
            Debug.Log ("TIMER countdown  time = " + time + " and instruction = " + instruction);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

            instruction.text = time.ToString();

            time -= 1;
        }

        instruction.text = "Blast Off!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your GetComponent might be returning nothing. Hard to tell since I don't know what gameObject you've attached the script to. I use a public to reference the Text UI element.

I got this to work in Unity 4.6. You must drag a reference to the Text component into the script. I attach my script to an empty gameObject called SceneController. The following works for me (countdown, then blastoff!).

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour {

    public int time;

    public Text instruction;

    public void Start () {
        startCountdown();
    }

    public void startCountdown() {
        StartCoroutine (countdown ());
        Debug.Log ("YES TIMER START!");
    }

    IEnumerator countdown() {
        while (time > 0) {
            Debug.Log ("TIMER countdown  time = " + time + " and instruction = " + instruction.text);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

            instruction.text = time.ToString();

            time -= 1;
        }

        instruction.text = "Blast Off!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am using exact same technique to reference a button object but it returns null. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?